# Any name of Sri Rama with Surya as he is solar race?

Tags: rama, name, surya, ayodhya

Looking for scripturally mentioned appellations for Lord Rama with a name of Surya.
Ramchandra is commonly used, but never something like Suryarama, Suryanana, Suryapati.
There could be reference to avoiding reference due to extreme brilliance of Surya.

Comment: Dinakarakula Divakara.

Comment: Very nice and beautiful rhythm to it. I would use it for naam. Thank you.